# Visible objects from a point in a polygon with holes in 2d

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry, polygons

The problem is the following:

Given a polygon ***P*** with ***h*** holes/objects and a point ***c*** inside ***P*** but outside the holes/objects. ***P*** has ***n*** given vertices and each hole/object ***h*** has ***4*** vertices (the holes/objects are rectangles).

Is there an efficient algorithm that can compute wich holes/objects are seen by ***c*** inside ***P*** ?

I have seen ***visibility poligon*** algorithms but I'm not interested in having a visual representation, but rather in time optimization and getting the list of observed holes/objects.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you dismiss the [visibility polygon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visibility_polygon). I think it's the right tool for this job, and not just for "having a visual representation":

Given a visibility polygon $V$, you can check whether an object $O$ can be seen from point $c$ by testing if (some part of) $O$ is inside $V$. This is true if any vertex of $O$ is inside $V$ or if any edge of $O$ intersects any edge of $V$. For complex polygons and/or many objects, these checks may be sped up by clever use of [space partitioning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_partitioning).